# Python, Pandas matching and finding contents in two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It is to check if the content in a data frame is also in another data frame.

The original data frame has 2 columns, IDs and its correspondent Fruits. There’s another data frame of different size (number of rows and columns)

In the original data frame, if the ID matches with the ID_1, and ID’s correspondent Fruit is either in ID_1’s correspondent Content or Content_1, create a new column to indicate it. (the wanted output is at the end of this question)

I tried to merge both the data frames for further manipulation. This is so far I have:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': ["4589", "14805", "23591", "47089", "56251", "85964", "235225", "322624", "342225", "380689", "480562", "5623", "85624", "866278"], 
'Fruit' : ["Avocado", "Blackberry", "Black Sapote", "Fingered Citron", "Crab Apples", "Custard Apple", "Chico Fruit", "Coconut", "Damson", "Elderberry", "Goji Berry", "Grape", "Guava", "Huckleberry"]
}

data_1 = {'ID_1': ["488", "14805", "23591", "470995", "56251", "85964", "5268", "322624", "342225", "380689", "480562", "5623"], 
'Content' : ["Kalo Beruin", "this is Blackberry", "Khara Beruin", "Khato Dosh", "Lapha", "Loha Sura", "Matichak", "Miniket Rice", "Mou Beruin", "Moulata", "oh Goji Berry", "purple Grape"],
'Content_1' : ["Jook-sing noodles", "Kaomianjin", "Lai fun", "Lamian", "Liangpi", "who wants Custard Apple", "Misua", "nana Coconut", "Damson", "Paomo", "Ramen", "Rice vermicelli"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[['ID', 'Fruit']]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df_1 = df_1[['ID_1', 'Content', 'Content_1']]

result = df.merge(df_1, left_on = 'ID', right_on = 'ID_1', how = 'outer')

for index, row in result.iterrows():
    if row["ID"] == row["ID_1"] and row["Fruit"] in row["Content"] or row["Fruit"] in row["Content_1"]:
        print row["ID"] + row["Fruit"]
```

It gives me *TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable*

(The version of Pandas I am using is v.0.20.3.)

**How can I achieve it? Thank you.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
#swap DataFrames with left join
result = df_1.merge(df, left_on = 'ID_1', right_on = 'ID', how = 'left')

#remove NaNs and create pattern with word boundary for check substrings
pat = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(result["Fruit"].dropna()))

#boolan mask - rewritten iterrows to vectorized way
mask = ((result["ID"] == result["ID_1"]) & 
         result["Content"].str.contains(pat, na=False) |
         result["Content_1"].str.contains(pat, na=False))

#remove unnecessary columns
result = result.drop(['ID','Fruit'], axis=1)
#add indicator column
result['matched'] = np.where(mask, 'Y', '')
```

---

```
print (result)
      ID_1             Content                Content_1 matched
0      488         Kalo Beruin        Jook-sing noodles        
1    14805  this is Blackberry               Kaomianjin       Y
2    23591        Khara Beruin                  Lai fun        
3   470995          Khato Dosh                   Lamian        
4    56251               Lapha                  Liangpi        
5    85964           Loha Sura  who wants Custard Apple       Y
6     5268            Matichak                    Misua        
7   322624        Miniket Rice             nana Coconut       Y
8   342225          Mou Beruin                   Damson       Y
9   380689             Moulata                    Paomo        
10  480562       oh Goji Berry                    Ramen       Y
11    5623        purple Grape          Rice vermicelli       Y
```

---

Old solution with `outer` join:

```
result = df.merge(df_1, left_on = 'ID', right_on = 'ID_1', how = 'outer')

pat = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(result["Fruit"].dropna()))

mask = ((result["ID"] == result["ID_1"]) & 
         result["Content"].str.contains(pat, na=False)|     
         result["Content_1"].str.contains(pat, na=False))

result['matched'] = np.where(mask, 'Y', '')
```

---

```
print (result)

        ID            Fruit    ID_1             Content  \
0     4589          Avocado     NaN                 NaN   
1    14805       Blackberry   14805  this is Blackberry   
2    23591     Black Sapote   23591        Khara Beruin   
3    47089  Fingered Citron     NaN                 NaN   
4    56251      Crab Apples   56251               Lapha   
5    85964    Custard Apple   85964           Loha Sura   
6   235225      Chico Fruit     NaN                 NaN   
7   322624          Coconut  322624        Miniket Rice   
8   342225           Damson  342225          Mou Beruin   
9   380689       Elderberry  380689             Moulata   
10  480562       Goji Berry  480562       oh Goji Berry   
11    5623            Grape    5623        purple Grape   
12   85624            Guava     NaN                 NaN   
13  866278      Huckleberry     NaN                 NaN   
14     NaN              NaN     488         Kalo Beruin   
15     NaN              NaN  470995          Khato Dosh   
16     NaN              NaN    5268            Matichak   

                  Content_1 matched  
0                       NaN          
1                Kaomianjin       Y  
2                   Lai fun          
3                       NaN          
4                   Liangpi          
5   who wants Custard Apple       Y  
6                       NaN          
7              nana Coconut       Y  
8                    Damson       Y  
9                     Paomo          
10                    Ramen       Y  
11          Rice vermicelli       Y  
12                      NaN          
13                      NaN          
14        Jook-sing noodles          
15                   Lamian          
16                    Misua
```

Comment: hello sir! you're always there helping the data frame questions! it's a perfect learning journey. wish you a great weekend!

Comment: @MarkK - You are welcome, just added another solutiion, I hope better.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of `row["Content"]` and `row["Content_1"]` are `NaN` in some cases.  `NaN` is a `float`, and it is also un-iterable - that's why you get the error.

You can use `try`/`except` to catch these:

```
for index, row in result.iterrows():
    try:
        if row["ID"] == row["ID_1"] and row["Fruit"] in row["Content"] or row["Fruit"] in row["Content_1"]:
            print( str(row["ID"]) + row["Fruit"])
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e, "for:")
        print(row)
```

I think your merge is working just fine though.  To get the output you specified, just add a `Matched` column that checks for `NaN` values:

```
result = df.merge(df_1, left_on = 'ID', right_on = 'ID_1', how = 'outer')
result["Matched"] = np.where(result.isnull().any(axis=1), "N", "Y")

result

        ID            Fruit    ID_1             Content  \
0     4589          Avocado     NaN                 NaN   
1    14805       Blackberry   14805  this is Blackberry   
2    23591     Black Sapote   23591        Khara Beruin   
3    47089  Fingered Citron     NaN                 NaN   
4    56251      Crab Apples   56251               Lapha   
5    85964    Custard Apple   85964           Loha Sura   

                  Content_1 Matched  
0                       NaN       N  
1                Kaomianjin       Y  
2                   Lai fun       Y  
3                       NaN       N  
4                   Liangpi       Y  
5   who wants Custard Apple       Y
```

Comment: wow! the one liner works! can I have your understanding that I choose the earlier reply with 2 solutions as an answer?

Comment: No problem - I think @Jezrael was just being more careful and complete.  His answer is great!